# Inherit DbSet to Apply Events on Add, Update and Remove Methods (EF Core .Net 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a Derived class from DBSet which would automatically add Domain events on add, update and remove methods.

Could anyone help me on this?

Here is my DbSetWithEvents.

```
public class DbSetWithEvents<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _db;

    public DbSetWithEvents(DbSet<TEntity> db)
    {
        _db = db;  
    } 

    public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity is IHasDomainEvent e)
        {
            e.DomainEvents.Add(EntityCreatedEvent.WithEntity(e));
        }
            
        return _db.Add(entity);
    }

    // Rest of code...

}
```

Here is my DBContext:

```
public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
{
      private readonly IPublisher _publisher;
      private readonly ILogger<ApiDbContext> _logger;
      private IDbContextTransaction? _currentTransaction;

     public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IPublisher publisher, 
          ILogger<ApiDbContext> logger) : base(options)
     {
          _publisher = publisher;
          _logger = logger;

         _logger.LogDebug("DbContext created");
     }

     public DbSet<Sdg> Sdgs => new DbSetWithEvents<Sdg>(Set<Sdg>());

     // Rest of the code
 }
```

The DbContext crashes when I call Any() method on the a derived DbSet.

Thanks for your help

Here is the Error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

Comment: Why do you need to derive from DbSet when your operations are on a member instance of DbSet?

Comment: I think you can achieve the same by overriding `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-savechangesasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken) - inside `SaveChagesAsync`, you can iterate over `ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted)`